# reading the output from dd command

Tags: bash, dd

I'm testing my network speed with a script and for it to calculate average speed I need to read the speed for each run.

command:

`dd if=InputFile of=OutputFile bs=4096k`

output:

```
64+0 records in
64+0 records out
268435456 bytes (268 MB) copied, 1.8519 s, 145MB/s
```

the problem is that the dd command always prints the output to stdout. I can manage to pipe it or write it to file so i can read the `145MB/s`

I've tried the following lines:

`dd if=InputFile of=OutputFile bs=4096k >> log.txt` - creates an empty file and prints to stdout

`dd if=InputFile of=OutputFile bs=4096k | grep *` - fails

```
echo `dd if=InputFile of=OutputFile bs=4096k` # fails
```

Comment: `dd` writes its messages to standard error. So: `dd ... 2>> log.txt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that dd does **not** print that output to stdout, but to **stderr**.

You have to redirect using `2> ...`, for example

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1 2> >( grep copied )
```

Comment: Or probably more like ...`| awk '/copied/ { print $1 }'`

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the PID of the dd process and setup a watch to send a USR1 signal to your liking. Then redirect that to a file!!!!